# MAUI app with WebView not remembering cookies on Android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, maui

I have a (.NET 7) MAUI app that shows a WebView where users can log in. On Android, it seems that cookies (or at least the session cookie) are not remembered when the user logs in with the “Remember me” option activated: When I close the app (also from the recent apps screen), wait some seconds and then reopen the app, the user has to log in again.

I use a custom WebViewClient (because of the `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading`) that is set in the `OnElementChanged` of the WebViewRenderer:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClientAndroid(Control.WebViewClient));
    }
```

In that CustomWebViewClient, I inject the original one to override all other (not needed) methods and preserve the behavior of MAUI:

```
public class CustomWebViewClientAndroid : WebViewClient
{
    private WebViewClient _defaultClient;

    public CustomWebViewClientAndroid(WebViewClient defaultClient) : base()
    {
        if (defaultClient == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(defaultClient));
        _defaultClient = defaultClient;
    }

    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, IWebResourceRequest? request)
    {
        var cancel = App.RootPage.Navigate(request.Url.ToString());
        if (!cancel)
            return _defaultClient.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        return cancel;
    }

    #region Default overrides (without custom implementation)
    public override bool ShouldOverrideKeyEvent(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, KeyEvent? e)
    {
        return _defaultClient.ShouldOverrideKeyEvent(view, e);
    }

    // All other possible overrides, implemented just like above
}
```

Do I need to handle the save of the cookies myself or is this a bug with MAUI or Android Webview? I expect the OS (Android) to handle the cookie store part.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can try to add the following code in the OnElementChanged method.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClientAndroid(Control.WebViewClient));
        Control.Settings.CacheMode = CacheModes.CacheElseNetwork;
        CookieManager.Instance.AcceptThirdPartyCookies(Control);
        CookieManager.Instance.SetAcceptThirdPartyCookies(Control, true);
        CookieManager.Instance.SetAcceptCookie(true);
    }
```

In addition, you can check the official document about [Setting cookies for the webview in the maui Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?pivots=devices-android) to set the cookie for the website you want.

Finally, I sugget you use the custom handler instead of the custom renderer in the .net maui. And you can put the code of the renderer's `OnElementChanged` method into the handler's `ConnectHandler` method.

For the detail steps, you can refer to the official wiki about [Porting Custom Renderers to Handlers on the github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Porting-Custom-Renderers-to-Handlers).

Comment: Unfortunately the additions to OnElementChanged didn't work. And I don't want to set a cookie manually, I would expect the webview to store the cookies just like the browser would do. Or are webview cookies getting deleted on app close?

Comment: The code I provided is about enabling the cookies. And I have tested some apps in my device such as browsers application. When I login in a website and then restart the app, I needed to login again. But it saved the account and password, I can login in directly. So the default behavior should be that the user need to login when the app restart every time. @Hamata6

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Browser application does remember your login as long as you marked the login as "remember me" / "stay logged in" etc. This will set the expiration date of the cookie, as cookies without expiration date are seen as this-session-only cookies and are removed on app close. But apparently, WebView cookies are not saved to persistent storage, even when you selected the "stay logged in" option. Now I know I need to handle the saving of the WebView cookies myself. Thanks for your clearance.